# How can I use unknown variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, wolframalpha

For example, I have an operation from Wolfram Alpha: `det({s+1,0},{0,s+1}})`. Wolfram solves it and shows me a result: `s^2 + 2s + 1`. How can I do such things (with unknown variables) in Matlab?

Comment: You need to use symbolic MATLAB, see e.g. the page http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [**Symbolic Math Toolbox**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html), this can be done using the following:

```
syms s;
det([s+1,0 ; 0,s+1])
```

which gives this:

```
ans =
(s + 1)^2
```

and if you want to get the expanded form i.e. `s^2 + 2*s + 1`, you can use [**`expand`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/expand.html?) function as follows:

```
syms s;
expand(det([s+1,0 ; 0,s+1]))
```